# math size in a table

Tags: tables, math-mode

I have a long table and I want to fit it in one page. Table has number and symbol entries. The size to the table can be reduced if I can reduce the font size. How can I reduce the font size in this case? I tried:

```
\begin{tabular}{|{\small}c|c|c|c} \end{tabular}
```

but it does not work for math.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: You could just wrap the entire table within a `\scalebox{0.6}{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}` using the `graphicx` pacakge.

Comment: It is not clear what you want because you don't provide an example. Scaling the font is not ideal. Have you thought of rotating the table or spreading the table over several pages? If not, have a look at the `rotating` and `longtable` packages.

Answer (score 4):

Put `\small` outside `tabular`. Here, `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are included to limit the scope of the size change to the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Ordinary text

\bgroup\small
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
goat & $a=b$ \\
$c=d$& pig
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Using `\tiny` in place of `\small` to emphasise the effect, the result is as shown.

[image]

Comment: I will try and back soon with results.

Answer (score 4):

rather than trying to shrink each element of the table separately, you might consider setting the table to its "normal" size with attractive spacing, then using `\scalebox{<scaling factor>}{<table content>}` to shrink the whole thing at one go.  this requires [the `graphicx` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and works equally well for all manner of items that need to be resized.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\MyTable}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c c|} \hline
    foo & a  \\
    $\sum = mc^2$ & $\int_0^1 f(x)$ \\\hline
\end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
\MyTable
\hspace{0.5cm}
\scalebox{0.8}{\MyTable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 7 seconds!! You mind if I add my example (now deleted) to your answer?

Comment: @PeterGrill -- what a generous offer!  of course i don't mind.  (i was about to delete my answer because yours is nicer.)  (i really love `\scalebox`; it's as close to a panacea as i've found for this kind of problem.)

Comment: \scalebox works. But, \bgroup\small does not work. I have put \tabular inside \table

Comment: Hi guys, longtable looks better approach, to break the table into multi-pages. I tried but instead of breaking the table, it reduces the row size to fit in one page. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: @Manojg longtable does nothing about row sizing it just calls the underlying tabular code.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the **relsize** package. It has commands `\smaller`, `\larger` and etc. that can be used inside many environments, or with braces in the document body, like: `\smaller{your table}`. The command accepts an argument for different sizes, e.g. `\smaller[2]`